# Flattening a list recursively - why doesn't my code return what I want?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

**Question**: Write a recursive function, `flattenList`, where `flattenList([2, 9, [2, 1, 13, 2], 8, [2, 6]])`, will return a list `[2, 9, 2, 1, 13, 2, 8, 2, 6]`.

**My code**:

```
def flattenList(lis):
    a = []
    for i in lis:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            a.append(i)
        else:
            flattenList(i)
    return a

print(flattenList([2, 9, [2, 1, 13, 2], 8, [2, 6]]))
```

While the desired output is `[2, 9, 2, 1, 13, 2, 8, 2, 6]`, I'm getting `[2, 9, 8]` (numbers not in sublists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive call doesn't add the data to the result list. So this:

```
flattenList(i)
```

should be:

```
a += flattenList(i)
```

Comment: @VictorLoh If my answer solved your problem, click the checkmark to the left of it to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `a.extend(flattenList(i))`. You're currently doing nothing with the recursive return.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function a generator and use the `yield from` syntax in python3:

```
def flattenList(lis):
    for i in lis:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            yield i
        else:
            yield from flattenList(i)


print(list(flattenList([2, 9, [2, 1, 13, 2], 8, [2, 6]])))
[2, 9, 2, 1, 13, 2, 8, 2, 6]
```